# c2470:'final' looks like a function definition,but there is no parameter list error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I ported a application to windows which I developed on linux on building the project I get the following error:

```
 error: C2470: 'final' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
```

This is my main.cpp

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
#include <tango.h>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <ctime>
#include <QMessageBox>


class  Application final : public QApplication {
    Application(int& argc, char** argv) : QApplication(argc, argv) {}
    virtual bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) override {
         // your code here


        try
            {
                return QApplication::notify( receiver, e );
            }
            catch(Tango::DevFailed e)
            {
                //QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Update Failed"),tr("Error updating values.Try again."));
            }
            catch(Tango::CommunicationFailed e)
            {
                //QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Communication with device failed"),tr("Error updating values.Try again."));
            }

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) try
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();



    return a.exec();
}

catch (Tango::DevFailed e)
{
    //QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Updating values failed"),tr("Error updating values.Try again."));
}
catch (Tango::CommunicationFailed e)
{
    //QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Communication Failed"),tr("Error updating values.Try again."));
}
```

This is my .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-12-08T09:19:31
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets




TARGET = FirstProject
TEMPLATE = app
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        firstscreen.cpp \
        secondscreen.cpp \
        thirdscreen.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\user_name\tango\ \
               C:\Users\user_name\omniORB4\ \
               C:\Users\user_name\omnithread.h





HEADERS  += firstscreen.h \
            C:\Users\user_name\tango\ \
            C:\Users\user_name\omniORB4\ \
            C:\Users\user_name\omnithread.h \
            secondscreen.h \
            thirdscreen.h


LIBS += -L -lomnithread \
        -L -lomniORB4 \
        -L -ltango


FORMS    += firstscreen.ui \
            secondscreen.ui \
            thirdscreen.ui
```

Could you let me know what I am missing here. I think the error is related to the c++ standards but I am not sure how I could resolve it.

Comment: This is because your compiler on Linux supports C++11, while your VS compiler does not.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How could I resolve it?

Comment: Upgrade to VS-2012 or VS-2013, which [support the `final` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj678985(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Additionally, add `CONFIG += c++11` to your qmake `.pro` file